# Locating don't work without Wifi

Tags: java, android, geolocation, location, google-maps-android-api-2

I have simple application which use `LocationClient`. Location is updated until wifi is enable.

**Cases:**

```
1. 3G on, wifi on (connected or not), GPS on- work
2. 3G on, wifi on (connected or not), GPS off- work
3. 3G off, wifi on (connected or not), GPS off- work
4. 3G on/off, wifi off, GPS on/off- doesn't work
```

Code:

```
public class PlayPositionProvider implements PositionProvider, FastestUpdate, GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "PLAY_POSITION_PROVIDER";
    private long period, fastest;
    private LocationClient client;
    private final Context context;
    private final PositionListener positionListener;
    private LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "LOCATION UPDATE");

            positionListener.onPositionUpdate(location);
        }
    };

    public PlayPositionProvider(Context context, long period, long fastest, PositionListener positionListener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.positionListener = positionListener;
        this.period = period;
        this.fastest = fastest;
    }

    @Override
    public void setUpdateInterval(long interval) {

        request.setInterval(interval);
        this.period = interval;
    }

    @Override
    public void setFastestInterval(long fastestInterval) {

        request.setFastestInterval(fastestInterval);
        this.fastest = fastestInterval;
    }

    private final LocationRequest request = LocationRequest.create();

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onConnected()");

        request.setInterval(period);
        request.setFastestInterval(fastest);

        request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        client.requestLocationUpdates(request, listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onDisconnected()");
        client.removeLocationUpdates(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "NOT IMPLEMENTED onConnectionFailed()");

    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdates() {

        client = new LocationClient(context, this, this);
        client.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void stopUpdates() {

        client.disconnect();

    }
}
```

In `AndroidManifest.xml` I have following permission:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<permission android:name="org.[PACKAGE_NAME].permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>

<!--Only in debug purpose-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"/>

<permission android:name="org.[PACKAGE_NAME].permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="org.[PACKAGE_NAME].permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
```

Comment: if ALL is off are u expecting to work?

Comment: @StathisAndronikos probably it should use BTS base station. Standard 2G connection is still available.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. We don't know if u are checking at all if GooglePlayServices are available..
2. With `requestLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);` you are stating you are interested in GPS data.. I am not sure but this might be the issue

Comment: 1. I check it in other places. Application was tested on several devices. 2. I try change this. But it doesn't help.